# Random Numbers In Range Not Random

Tags: javascript, random

I've been trying to generate random numbers between 1 and 10 million, but was finding that none of the numbers generated were lower than 1 million. I wrote this code to test the problem. This code selects ten million random numbers between 1 and ten million and outputs the lowest number. I'd expect to get at least something in the 100-1000 range at least, but it;s always at least 1 million. What have I missed?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vhLoqz8g/

```js
var lowest=10000000;
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  var g=Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000000 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  if (g<lowest)
  {
  lowest=g;
  }
}

document.write(g);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should output `lowest` and not `g` at the end of your loop:

```js
var lowest=1e8;
for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
  var g=Math.floor(Math.random()* 1e7) + 1;
  if (g<lowest) lowest=g;
}

console.log(lowest)
```

Comment: I feel so utterly ashamed. I knew it would be simple. Thank you so much! Can't believe I made such a stupid mistake..... oops.